# Detect which div finger is over with touchmove event

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to detect which div my finger would be over when using `touchmove`, I’ve only been able to find the original div the`touchmove` event started on...

Comment: no code? i would suggest attaching a div to your finger sliding, and check if it hits anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get all elements at a certain spot with the `document.elementsFromPoint(x, y);` method.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.elementsFromPoint

To get just the top element use `document.elementFromPoint(x, y);`.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.elementFromPoint